# Conda : Segmentation Fault error with all input command after installing conda install groakat::libc

Tags: segmentation-fault, centos, conda

I'm using the mamba environment on CentOS 7.

I also encountered the error "undefined reference to `**memcpy@GLIBC_2.14**'" repeatedly when trying to build hdf5.

So, I wanted to update related libraries, guessing it might be 'libc', and attempted to install it using the command **"conda listall groakat:libc".**

In installing sequence, any error is not appearad (i.e Collecting metadata, Environment solving, etc)

But after all, my enviorment is totally not working.

First, When I input command anything. Same message printed : **"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"**

Second, When I make new terminal. "-bash: **[username]/mambaforge/etc/profile.d/conda.sh: No such file or directory:** " Moreover, in left side status bar CentOS GUI directory, there is any folder or files.

Third, in that time, my office computer is connected with google remote destop. So I check if there is same symptom. Because even if installing 'libc' makes this problem, my office computer is not yet affected via source ./~bashrc.
And so on, there is same output message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" with any input command. But in my office computer shows files and folders in left GUI status bar.

Fourth, Whether these my operations affect whole server enviornment, check some basic command working well, enter command kinda 'which ls', 'which cd' , 'which cp'.. etc. and there is also same "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" message. But interest thing is, when I put message i.e 'ls' and press tab key (not enter key)  it gives me list consisting of ls* binaries. Also my custom alias well.

In conclusion, in my guess, it seems like

1. Any folder or file are not deleted. Just These problem is related to conda or mamba.
2. But, as meaning of Segmentation fault message, there`s some crash (about library-environment)

And I want to know

In my situation, I have a huge restrictions that I can not enter any CUI command.

1. So, with delete file and folder manually on GUI bar, this situation can be solved?
2. To be honestly, just i want to know any actions what can I do to solve this problem.
3. Addtionaly, what is real causes about "undefined reference to `**memcpy@GLIBC_2.14**'" ?

Thanks, I hope there is a solution.

Thanks again to read my long texts.

hdp

Soultion : [Solution found : Segmentation fault with install glibc on Conda enviornment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974192/solution-found-segmentation-fault-with-install-glibc-on-conda-enviornment)

Comment: Why build `hdf5` in the first place? The whole point of Conda is that it has precompiled everything.