# How can I treat unaccessible conda/mamba enviornment?

Tags: segmentation-fault, conda, centos7, glibc

Yesterday, I experienced a very confusing and perhaps embarrassing incident (due to a lack of knowledge).

([Conda : Segmentation Fault error with all input command after installing conda install groakat::libc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77969187/conda-segmentation-fault-error-with-all-input-command-after-installing-conda-i) (my post))

I learned below thing :

Updating glibc is a very risky operation because most binaries and libraries are already tailored to the installed version of glibc, and simply installing conda packages does not update their dependencies.

So, I found a duct-tape-solution for this problem. At that time, there were no restrictions on entering commands like echo or export in the bash shell, so by entering export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" ", I disconnected all the links, and then normal operation was possible in the command-line interface (CUI).

Now, when I press the tab key in an empty command prompt, only the conda binary is not displayed, so the issue seems to be only with conda profile loading.

The solution I'm thinking of is to uninstall and reinstall conda.
However, since conda itself is currently broken, it seems impossible to software-wise remove conda. Is there any solution?

Again, I hope there`s a solution for this problem.

Thanks again users to read my long text.

hdp

Soultion : [Solution found : Segmentation fault with install glibc on Conda enviornment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77974192/solution-found-segmentation-fault-with-install-glibc-on-conda-enviornment)

Comment: Umm.. I found a solution myself.

\1) export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=" "
\2)